# UILabel not responding to frame changes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel, autolayout

I am trying to reposition a `UILabel` in Xcode Version 4.6.3 that was originally setup/positioned in a storyboard, setting the frame does not do anything...

```
[[cell sizeLabelData] setFrame:CGRectMake(123, 90, 130, 35)];
[[cell sizeLabelData] setFrame:CGRectMake(  0,  0, 130, 35)]; // Same as above
```

I certainly have the right item as changing its color works just fine.

```
[[cell sizeLabelData] setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Its more than likely some autoLayout issue as it seems to want to stay in the same place no matter what. I have checked and the *"Use Autolayout"* check box is turned off for the storyboard, is there another option / setting that I need to change to get this working? I am not using auto layout as everything is positioned either in the storyboard or programatically at runtime.

If I log the frame it is getting the right values: `FRAME: {{123, 90}, {130, 35}}`

Comment: the instance is valid?`[cell sizeLabelData]`

Comment: what type of UITableViewCell are you using in storyboard for your prototype cell?

Comment: The UITableViewCell is a "custom" prototype cell from my own UITableViewCell Subclass.

Comment: I have found the problem, there was a test routine that was getting called and overwriting the frame values, it should not have been doing that but it was getting called right at the end and thus overwriting anything previous. Much appreciated, thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will change the frame if
`[cell sizeLabeldata]` is a **valid memory** and is a **connected outlet instance.**

Try setting the `backgroundcolor` of the label and see the frame varies or not.

```
[[cell sizeLabelData] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```